# Android Notifications not showing on emulator running API 27

Tags: java, android, notifications, kotlin

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I have an Alarm Receiver object that seems to work when triggering notifications on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running API 19 I got a few years ago. But the code apparently has some bugs as nothing what so ever gets triggered on the emulator. I've been reading that it is necessary with the newer API's that you create a NotificationChannel object but even with this object in my code I can't seem to get the desired result.

```
 class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, NotificationActivity::class.java)

        val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity::class.java)
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent)

        val pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "DailyJoke")

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            //Here's the notificationChannel object. It doesn't seem to work, idk why
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("DailyJoke", "Name", importance)

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            Builder(context, notificationChannel.id)
        } else {
            Builder(context)
        }


            val sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + "raw/drumroll")


            builder = builder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                    .setTicker("TICKER Text")
                    .setContentText("KDW setContentText")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setChannelId("DailyJoke")
                    .setSound(sound)

                notificationManager.notify(1, builder!!.build())

    }
}
```